# Swift 4 Repeating Local Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying it make a notification that will trigger every day at the same time (7:00AM). I am able to get the notification to trigger if I use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` but not `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` which is what I really want. This is what I have currently:

In AppDelegate.swift I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (didAllow, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

And I remembered to import `UserNotifications` too

When the user presses a button in ViewController.swift this is run:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Do your daily review"
    content.badge = 1

    let triggerTime = DateComponents.init(hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerTime, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "dailyNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil
```

Could you please explain to me what is wrong here, and why `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` works but `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried adding a check for any error in the completion handler the same way you have for your first code example? And how do you know it. doesn't work?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did what you suggested and it reports no error. I believe it doesn't work because I changed my computer's time to the time that it should trigger of tomorrow, and it didn't notify me. I also tried the beginning  of every hour just to rule out any possible time-zone related issues

Comment: How do you set up the delegate?

Comment: Simply print the `triggerTime`, and you’ll see what type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original code works fine, I just needed to do my testing differently. For some reason, if I set the time in my code to 7:00AM and then simulate that time on my Mac, it doesn't work, but if the time that I set it to is the real time of the day + 1 min, and I wait a real minute without changing my computer's time, it works. Perhaps Apple stops notifications that come soon after the time jumps to stop people from having notification troubles when they change timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will fix your issue but you are setting a DateComponent directly from an init. I would propose you to do it by initializing an empty DateComponent and only set the hours as you want.

So, could you try to do this :

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Do your daily review"
content.badge = 1

var triggerTime = DateComponents()
triggerTime.hour = 7

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerTime, repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "dailyNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

I did it from my own side and it works.

I hope it may help.

Comment: Why would the `init` method be a problem? Please elaborate on that preferable with some proof for your claims.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it hasn't fixed my problem. Could you provide a link to your project so I can try to spot what else you've done differently?